# LINQ to read file XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

i have this file XML :

[this is my XML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuKtD.png)

How i can get e a C# code using LINQ?? 
I try this code :

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\temp\image.xml");

        var lv1s = from lv1 in doc.Descendants("field")
                   select new
                   {
                       Header = lv1.Attribute("type").Value,
                       Children = lv1.Descendants("value")
                   };

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var lv1 in lv1s)
        {
            result.AppendLine(lv1.Header);
            foreach (var lv2 in lv1.Children)
                result.AppendLine("     " + lv2.Attribute("type").Value);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
```

but i have no result!

Comment: Refer [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/reading-xml-file-through-linq-a-few-tips/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your children have no attributes at all, just values, dont they?

What if you change your cycle like this, is it what you want?

```
foreach (var lv1 in lv1s)
{
    result.AppendLine(lv1.Header);
    foreach (var lv2 in lv1.Children)
    {
        //result.AppendLine("     " + lv2.Attribute("type").Value); // THERE ARE NO ATTRIBUTES
        result.AppendLine("     " + lv2.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have just :

    `<field> type="AAA">
    <value>XXX</value>
</field>`

So, i don't have any result!

Comment: Have you tried on your file what I suggested? With that simple file it works: _<document><field type="AAA"><value>XXX</value></field></document>_

Comment: yes , i tried your new code, but i still have no result
i don't know what i should do?

Comment: Thats weird, are you sure you are looking to the correct file? If you put breakpoint on line with _var lv1s = from lv1 in doc.Descendants("field")_ and check your doc variable, can you see the content of file?

Comment: i am sorry, i am beginning in XML..
i tried var lv1s = from lv1 in doc.Descendants("field")....but i have any result!!

Comment: Can you see this? https://codeshare.io/W6COW copy it to your visual studio..there is xml file also..works with that..maybe try run Visual studio as administrator, dont know what to say more

Answer (score 0):

Very thanks, with the code which you give me, i still have problem..

but i found the solution with other method:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"C:\temp\image.xml");


        XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("value");
        for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(elemList[i].InnerXml);
        }
```

and if i want a value specified ,for exemple type="line1":

```
string aa = elemList[1].InnerXml;
```